# JavaFX - Borders of ImageView and Pane do not scale / zoom properly inside ScrollPane

Tags: image, javafx, javafx-8, scale, zooming

in order to achieve something like **a minimap**, I used a `StackPane` to layer a `Pane` on top of an `ImageView`. I bound the the scaling x- and y-properties of the `StackPane` to a `Slider` in order to achieve a zooming effect. I added a few `Circle` objects to the `Pane`. These circles should of course also be zoomable (which they are), but in this case more importantly, they **should stay at their relative position** when scaling happens. The following picture shows what the GUI looks like so far.

[image: Unscaled Minimap]

As of yet, I have distinguished two problematic cases.

---

**Problem A - Correct positions but 'out of bounds'**

In this more simple case, everything works fine, except for the fact that zooming in on the image seemingly makes it exceed the bounds of the `StackPane`. As a result, you cannot scroll to the image's border anymore. Check the next screenshot to see what I mean.

[image: Problem A - Scaling 'out of bounds']

---

**Problem B - 'In bounds' but out of position**

To make the `StackPane` grow appropriately, I bound its size properties to the zoom factor multiplied  with the image's size. However, I am pretty sure that this approach somehow messes with the underlying coordinate structure, because now the circle 'leaves' its position at a scale factor > 1. Said behaviour is depicted in the last screenshot.

[image]

---

I have added my code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScalingProblem extends Application {

    private static final String IMAGE_URL = "https://st2.depositphotos.com/3034795/10774/i/950/depositphotos_107745620-stock-photo-labyrinth-or-maze.jpg";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        // Prepare the main part of the GUI.
        Image backgroundImage = new Image(IMAGE_URL);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(backgroundImage);
        Circle circle = new Circle(40, Color.ORANGE);
        circle.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        circle.setStrokeWidth(5);
        Pane layer = new Pane(circle);
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(imageView, layer);
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(stackPane);
        scrollPane.setPannable(true);

        // Prepare the controls on the left side.
        Slider xSlider = new Slider();
        Slider ySlider = new Slider();
        Slider radiusSlider = new Slider();
        Slider zoomSlider = new Slider();
        VBox vBox = new VBox(xSlider, ySlider, radiusSlider, zoomSlider);
        vBox.setSpacing(10);
        vBox.setPrefWidth(200);

        // Adjust the sliders.
        adjustSlider(xSlider, 0, 1000, 50);
        adjustSlider(ySlider, 0, 1000, 50);
        adjustSlider(radiusSlider, 0, 100, 15);
        adjustSlider(zoomSlider, 0, 3, 1);
        zoomSlider.setMajorTickUnit(1);
        zoomSlider.setMinorTickCount(1);
        zoomSlider.setShowTickMarks(true);
        zoomSlider.setShowTickLabels(true);

        // Do all necessary binding.
        circle.centerXProperty().bind(xSlider.valueProperty());
        circle.centerYProperty().bind(ySlider.valueProperty());
        circle.radiusProperty().bind(radiusSlider.valueProperty());
        stackPane.scaleXProperty().bind(zoomSlider.valueProperty());
        stackPane.scaleYProperty().bind(zoomSlider.valueProperty());
        /*
         * So far, I always needed to make the StackPane's size grow / shrink depending on the zoom level. If the
         * following two lines are commented out, zooming in will make the ImageView exceed the bounds of the StackPane.
         * As a result, the StackPane does not 'grow' appropriately so that you cannot pan the view to see the edges of
         * the background.
         */
        stackPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(zoomSlider.valueProperty().multiply(backgroundImage.getWidth()));
        stackPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(zoomSlider.valueProperty().multiply(backgroundImage.getHeight()));

        // Piece the GUI together.
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(scrollPane);
        root.setLeft(vBox);
        root.setPrefHeight(300);
        root.setPrefWidth(500);

        // Show the stage.
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    private void adjustSlider(Slider slider, double min, double max, double start) {
        slider.setMin(min);
        slider.setMax(max);
        slider.setValue(start);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ScrollPane` uses the unmodified layout bounds to determine the content size. This does not include the scaling transformation. To prevent the content from growing beyond the scrollable area, wrap the scaled node in a `Group`.

Modify the `ScrollPane` creation like this:

```
ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(new Group(stackPane));
```

and remove the binding to the `prefWidth`/`prefHeight`, i.e. delete the following lines:

```
stackPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(zoomSlider.valueProperty().multiply(backgroundImage.getWidth()));
stackPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(zoomSlider.valueProperty().multiply(backgroundImage.getHeight()));
```

Comment: I have been bashing my head in over this for more than 2 days. THANK YOU!